# Order by one column if not null, otherwise by another column, columns are of not matching types

Tags: postgresql

I have an application that uses PostgreSQL as RDBMS. There is a table containing orders placed by customers. The table has an `id` as primary key, an `order_number`  (integer) and a `created_at` field (timestamp). `id` and `created_at` are assigned automatically when the row is created, the `order_number` is assigned "manually" (when the person performing the order entry process receives the order confirmation, he presses a button and the order_number is assigned as `MAX(order_number) + 1`, this can happen almost immediately or after a few days, or the order can be cancelled so it never receives a number). In the table there are quite a lot of rows with `NULL` in the `order_number` column: the cancelled and pending confirmation orders. This is an excerpt from the table:

```
id |order_number|created_at             |
---+------------+-----------------------+
201|      210807|2021-06-09 15:24:17.000|
207|            |2021-06-15 13:51:00.000|
203|      210831|2021-06-11 13:34:02.000|
197|            |2021-06-07 13:37:54.000|
196|      210781|2021-06-04 08:33:59.000|
206|      210849|2021-06-15 08:15:42.000|
202|      210817|2021-06-10 10:13:27.000|
199|      210820|2021-06-09 13:21:09.000|
205|      210819|2021-06-11 14:12:20.000|
198|      210785|2021-06-07 14:04:31.000|
200|      210830|2021-06-09 15:03:36.000|
204|      210818|2021-06-11 13:51:06.000|
208|      210878|2021-06-15 14:20:21.000|
```

I need to order the table by `order_number`, if it's not null, otherwise by `created_at`; that's what I want to achieve:

```
id |order_number|created_at             |
---+------------+-----------------------+
196|      210781|2021-06-04 08:33:59.000|
197|            |2021-06-07 13:37:54.000
198|      210785|2021-06-07 14:04:31.000|
201|      210807|2021-06-09 15:24:17.000|
202|      210817|2021-06-10 10:13:27.000|
204|      210818|2021-06-11 13:51:06.000|
205|      210819|2021-06-11 14:12:20.000|
199|      210820|2021-06-09 13:21:09.000|
200|      210830|2021-06-09 15:03:36.000|
203|      210831|2021-06-11 13:34:02.000|
206|      210849|2021-06-15 08:15:42.000|
207|            |2021-06-15 13:51:00.000|
208|      210878|2021-06-15 14:20:21.000|
```

The clause `ORDER BY order_number, created_at` will not work. I tried `ORDER BY COALESCE(order_number, created_at)` as suggested in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003413/order-by-column1-if-column1-is-not-null-otherwise-order-by-column2), but that doesn't work because there is a mismatch between types.

As a last note, I cannot use the `id` column, because sometime the order number is entered some time after the initial order entry, as you can see in the example ids 199, 200, 203.

This is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f4e7e1/2) with sample data.

If can help, I implemented in the application (c++) the logic above; data are in a `std::vector` of `Order *` objects, then I use sort:

`sort(orders.begin(), orders.end(), OrderComparator);`

`OrderComparator` is implemented as follows:

```
bool OrderComparator(Order * one, Order * two) {
   if(one->getOrderNumber()>0 && two->getOrderNumber()>0) {
       return one->getOrderNumber() > two->getOrderNumber();
   }
   return one->getCreatedAt() > two->getCreatedAt();
}
```

Comment: The logic for this is somewhat more complex than you describe. What would happen if order number `210820` had a create date of `2021-06-04 09:00:00`? Where would the row for id 197 go? After id 196 or after id 199? Why?

Comment: The logic for where to interleave the rows without an order number isn't clear... Is it some sort of "after the row with the max create date that is still lower than this create date" logic?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Well, you are right, that logic is not well defined. I would say that when a row is without a number, the list should be "scanned" from the beginning and the row inserted before the first row that has a timestamp greater that the row to be inserted. Anyway, I'm not really picky: my real concern is to avoid a block of rows without a number at the beginning or at the end of the list. This is my implementation in c++ (the rows are in a vector):

Comment: Looks like an extention of a gaps-and-islands problem. Consider creating a fiddle with your data to save those who might want to give it a shot the trouble.

Comment: Fiddle created, link in the question.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible in PostgreSQL:  In Oracle, you'd create a UDT with an `ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION`

Comment: @MichaelKutz - in PostgreSQL, **anything** is possible! :-) It's renowned for its extensibility! To the OP, Giorgio, if could put your table and data into a dbfiddle (dbfiddle.uk), I'll take a  look. You should do this for every question of this sort - it helps eliminate duplication of effort on behalf of those trying to answer, removes the possibility of typos and provides a single source of truth! Help us to help you! :-)

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW I put everything in sqlfiddle, link in the question.

Comment: @GiorgioR My bad - missed it - molto dispiaciuto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but essentially, you'll want to calculate a value to be the *first* sort column. Essentially computing a "sort" value that will figure out the "nearest" `order_number` for the rows that have a `null` `order_number`, then you can sort on that, and use additional columns in your `ORDER BY` to put the `null` values in the right order.

In this example, I get the non-null `order_number` of the row that was created most immediately prior to the `null` row, and use that as the first sort column. This puts things in approximately the right order--then you can use additional ordering columns to control how the `null` order numbers show up in relation to the "closest order number" that was used for the initial sorting.

```sql
WITH orders_cte AS (
      SELECT *,
             (SELECT o2.order_number 
                FROM orders AS o2
                WHERE o2.created_at <= o.created_at
                AND o2.order_number IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY created_at DESC
               LIMIT 1) AS primary_sort 
      FROM orders AS o
      )
SELECT id, order_number, created_at
FROM orders_cte
ORDER BY primary_sort, order_number, created_at
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks!